# Trying to scan a list of directories with powershell and output the oldest file

Tags: powershell

I am working on a powershell script that should be able to scan a list of different directories and output the oldest file in the directory

Th current script allows me to put one path. How can I adjust the script so I can add multiple paths?

```
$FileDate = (Get-Date -Format g)
$path = "C:\Users"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $FileDate -and -not $_.PSIsContainer) {
        $FileDate = $_.LastWriteTime
        $OldFile = $_.FullName
    }
}

Write-Host 'The oldest file on the system is: ' $OldFile
$FileDate
```

Comment: When you carefully (re-)read the help for [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1) you will notice that you can provide more than one `-Path` at a time.

Comment: Possible simplification: `$oldestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Are you looking for the oldest file in _each_ of the specified directories?

Comment: no I am looking for oldest file between all the directories

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could add multiple paths. I tried it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I realized you could add multiple paths with a common, then loop through.

```
$FileDate = (Get-Date -Format g)
$path = "C:\Users","e:\test"


Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $FileDate -and -not $_.PSIsContainer) {
$FileDate = $_.LastWriteTime
$OldFile = $_.FullName
}
}
Write-Host 'The oldest file on the system is: ' $OldFile
$FileDate
```